# Both 12.10&12.04 Installation freeze

Tags: 12.04, installation, 12.10, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

A friend of mine is having problems installing Ubuntu.
We've tried both 12.10 and 12.04 ver. but each time we get [image] and then we got stuck.
His comp is:

```
Motherboard: ASUS P5G41-M LX
CPU: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E6500 @ 2.93GHz
DISK: Disk 500.1 GB SAMSUNG HD502HJ
RAM:
Slot 1  DDR2 (PC2-6400) 2048 MB Kingston
Slot 2  DDR2 (PC2-6400) 2048 MB Hyundai Electronics
Graph card: NVIDIA GeForce GT 240
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried to boot with nomodeset ?

Answer (score 0):

Enable nomodeset and noapic parameters. Additionally, you can also try noalpic and acpi=off but nomodeset generally works

[image: enabling boot parameters]

Comment: Ok guy we installed the system but after we cannot start installed system up, again the same effect.

Comment: When you see the grub screen press 'e' to edit boot parameters. On a line, you'll see `quiet splash $vt_handoff`. Next to it, add `noapic nomodeset` and press Ctrl + X to boot